# Accessing named indexed properties

Tags: c++, properties, command-line-interface

I am using a DLL that provides a class with a named indexed property called Tag

The following C# code works nicely

```
// create an instance of the class 'ticks'
...

// set tag value to 46 for contract
 ticks.set_Tag("contract",46 );

// get tag value for contract
 int idx = (int)ticks.get_Tag("contract");
```

I would like to use this from C++/CLI

The methods set_Tag and get_Tag are not visible

This code works fine ( or at least it compiles ) to set the value

```
ticks->Tag["contract"] = 46;
```

But accessing the value fails to compile

```
int idx = ticks->Tag["contract"];

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'int'
```

If I force ( cast ) this to an int, it contains garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that `idx` is a boxed `Int32`, not an `int`. You can use

```
int idx = safe_cast<int>(ticks->Tag["contract"]);
```

to [*unbox*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/477cfz00.aspx) the number.

Comment: I miss the good old days, when all you had to write was (int) and the compiler worked out for itself what was needed.